# How to get text and input text in mat-form-field using robot framework

Tags: html, selenium, robotframework

I need help with input the text and get a text from the mat-form-field element
I need to write something on the mat-form-field element

But when I am trying to use the "input text" keyword of selenium I am getting the below error message

```
input text xpath=//div/auto-complete/mat-form-field  "'Text'"
```

> InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state*

and when I am trying to use

```
get text xpath=//div/auto-complete/mat-form-field
```

It's returning nothing.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 pad10right">
  <auto-complete>
    <mat-form-field>
      <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper">
        <div class="mat-form-field-flex">
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-form-field>
  </auto-complete>
</div>
```

Comment: I am hoping that you have given proper tab spaces between the keywords (as required by RF). Having said that, could you post the website link here to inspect the element?

Comment: Sorry but this is an internal organization tool that cannot be accessed outside

Comment: Probably there is an input element within that html which you need to target.

Comment: @Matthew That's the real problem there is no input element.

Comment: Hmm, my understanding of mat-form-field is lacking but from examples I've seen, they're not an input field, they usually wrap around an input element. So in normal use can a user enter anything into any field in the front end? At the moment it sounds like the HTML is incorrect but maybe show some more in the snippet if it's not business sensitive

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only workaround is to use `Press Keys`

```
Press Keys    xpath=//app-input/mat-form-field    1    2    3    q    a    z
```

And after inspecting page, I was able use `Input Text` and `Get Element Attribute`

```
    Input Text    xpath=//app-input/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div[3]/input    123qaz2
    ${text}=    Get Element Attribute
    ...    xpath=//app-input/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div[3]/input
    ...    value
    Log To Console    Text ${text}
```